# C#: LINQ query with split and parsing

Tags: c#, linq, split

I have an object with a String field containing a comma separated list of integers in it. I'm trying to use LINQ to retrieve the ones that have a specific number in the list.

Here's my approach

```
from p in source 
where (p.Keywords.Split(',').something.Contains(val)) 
select p;
```

Where p.Keywords is the field to split.

I've seen the following in the net but just doesn't compile:

```
from p in source 
where (p.Keywords.Split(',').Select(x=>x.Trim()).Contains(val)) 
select p;
```

I'm a LINQ newbie, but had success with simpler queries.

**Update:**
Looks like I was missing some details:

- source is a List containing the object with the field Keywords with strings like 1,2,4,7
- Error I get is about x not being defined.

Comment: What's the compilation error?

Comment: What is `source` ? What is the error you are getting ? Your second code snippet should compile fine, if source is `List<T>/IEnumerable<T>` where your class contains a property `Keywords` of type string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of selecting numbers that are greater than 3:

```
string str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8";
var numbers = str.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).Where(num => num > 3); // 4,5,6,7,8
```

If you have a list then change the `Where` clause:

```
string str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8";
List<int> relevantNums = new List<int>{5,6,7};
var numbers = str.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).Where(num => relevantNums.Contains(num)); // 5,6,7
```

If you are **not** looking for number but for strings then:

```
string str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8";
List<string> relevantNumsStr = new List<string>{"5","6","7"};
var numbers = str.Split(',').Where(numStr => relevantNumsStr.Contains(numStr)); // 5,6,7
```

Comment: Having to post three different answers packed into one is a clear sign the question is either not clear enough, or too broad to be reliably answered in the first place.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - I have to agree with you :)

Comment: I'm using a .cs file but tried your first option with this error: error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected

Comment: Second sentence on my question says: "I'm trying to use LINQ to retrieve the ones that have a specific number in the list."

Comment: Although is not the exact code I ended using, it contains and explains a lot about how I got to the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can achieve this. For simplicity I did to string on the number to check for, but you get the point.

```
    // class to mimic what you structure
    public class MyObj
    {
        public string MyStr{get;set;}
    }

    //method
    void Method()
    {
            var myObj  = new List <MyObj>
            { 
                new  MyObj{ MyStr="1,2,3,4,5"},
                new  MyObj{ MyStr="9,2,3,4,5"}
            };
            var num =9;
            var searchResults = from obj  in myObj
                                where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.MyStr) &&  
                                    obj.MyStr.Split(new []{','})
                                        .Contains(num.ToString())
                                select obj;
            foreach(var item in searchResults)                           
            Console.WriteLine(item.MyStr);                           
    }
```

Comment: This looks like script, I'm using C# but lead me to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work on a .cs file. I'm learning C# as well coming from Java world, some constructs might be unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers, although not in the right language they led me to the answer:

```
from p in source where (p.Keywords.Split(',').Contains(val.ToString())) select p;
```

Where val is the number I'm looking for.